# Relation "schema.f()" does not exist calling function from Node-Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Using `pg` aka `node-postgres` v8.3

I have a PostgreSQL (v12) function named `f()` under `myschema`. It runs perfectly in pgAdmin 4.25 as

```
select * from myschema.f()
```

Calling it in Nodes:

```
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const pool = new Pool(
    {
        user: ...,
    }
);
const pgCallF = (paramless, cbFunc) =>
{
    var sql = 'select * from "myschema"."f()"'; // same err if myschema.f(), but ok for query like 'select * from myschema.table1'
    pool.query(sql)
        .then
        (
            good =>
            {...},
            bad =>
            {...}
        )
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            next();
        })
}
```

got

> relation "myschema.f()" does not exist.

Comment: Try this: 'select * from "myschema"."f"()'

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to call a function with `node-postgres`:

```
var sql = 'select * from myschema.f();';
```

1. **no need to double-quote schema and function name.**
2. **append semi-colon at the end.**

How I figured it out?

- first I verified the userID making the call has permission.
- then turned on trace/log to see what exactly passed into PG. (it's the same text literal which is `select * from "myschema"."f()"`)
- instead of test in pgAdmin, I believe SQL Shell (psql) is where I supposed to test the statement. Launched it, appended failed statement with semi-colon got the same *Relation not exist*.
- removed double-quoted but appending a semicolon worked.

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses are part of the function call, not part of the function name.  They do not go inside the quotes (which are unneeded anyway).

Now you *could* create a function with parentheses in its name in which case they would go inside the quotes, with another pair going outside when you use the function, but 1) you didn't do that, and 2) it would be a diabolical idea anyway.